# Swift Google Places in a tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-places-api

what I am trying to do is create a tableView that has the name of a bunch of different restaurants taken from Google's place api. Google recommends getting the place_id, which I am able to do, and use that place_id to get the name of the restaurants, which I am able to do. The problem that I am having is that to put the name of the restaurant into a tableView I will need an array that is outside the function, so I append the place names that I got using the place_id to the array outside the function. All is good here and it compiles with no error, it is just when the app loads that the tableView is blank, and I check using a print statement and it states that the array is empty.

This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GooglePlaces
import GoogleMaps
import Firebase
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!



var arrayedName = [String]()


var http = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.392788,-73.450949&radius=5000&type=restaurant&key=KEY_HERE"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
   other()
}


func other() {
    Alamofire.request(http).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            let results = swiftyJsonVar["results"].arrayValue
            for result in results {
                let id = result["place_id"].stringValue
                var arrayed = [String]()
                arrayed.append(id)
                for i in 0..<arrayed.count {
                    let array = arrayed[i]
                    self.placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(array, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let place = place else {
                            print("No place details for \(arrayed[i])")
                            return
                        }

                        let placeName = place.name
                        self.arrayedName.append(placeName)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayedName.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell
    cell.nameLbl.text = "\(arrayedName[indexPath.row])"
    return cell
 }
```

}

No matter what I do I just can't get the array to be populated. I checked the info plist, and everything I need is there, but I think that the problem is in the other() function. Another thing that I have tried is to recreate the code from the other() function and add it to the cellForRowAt, but it just crashes. That looked like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell
        Alamofire.request(http).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                let results = swiftyJsonVar["results"].arrayValue
                for result in results {
                    let id = result["place_id"].stringValue
                    var arrayed = [String]()
                    arrayed.append(id)
                    for i in 0..<arrayed.count {
                        let array = arrayed[i]
                        self.placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(array, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
                            if let error = error {
                                print("Lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                return
                            }
                            guard let place = place else {
                                print("No place details for \(arrayed[i])")
                                return
                            }

                            let placeName = place.name

                            var arrayName = [String]()
                            arrayName.append(placeName)
                            cell.nameLbl.text = "\(arrayName[indexPath.row])"

                        })
                    }
                }



            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I am out of ideas on what to do. If there is anyone who can help, I am thankful. If there is anything else that I can answer please ask. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the `arrayedName` is empty so you will not see any item in the `tableView`. But once all the places name are appended to this array you need to reload the `tableView` to see the new data. You should keep the `cellForRowAt` same as you tried in the first attempt without any API call. I have updated the `other` method as below so now it should work

```
func other() {
    Alamofire.request(http).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            let results = swiftyJsonVar["results"].arrayValue

            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            for result in results {
                let id = result["place_id"].stringValue

                dispatchGroup.enter()

                self.placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(id, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
                   if let error = error {
                      print("Lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                      dispatchGroup.leave()
                      return
                   }
                   guard let place = place else {
                      print("No place details for \(id)")
                      dispatchGroup.leave()
                      return
                   }

                   self.arrayedName.append(place.name)
                   dispatchGroup.leave()
               })
           }
           dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) {
              self.tableView.reloadData()
           } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked wonderfully. I was just curious on how exactly dispatchgroup works. Thank you for the help